# How to disable motion blur on a single object in Blender 2.8 EEVEE?

Tags: eevee-render-engine

How to disable motion blur on a single object in Blender 2.8 EEVEE ?

Answer (score 2):

The [motion blur](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/render/eevee/motion_blur.html) currently available in Eevee is camera based.

That means it compares the entire image between two frames and blurs all motion, it is not capable of blurring single objects.